# I am trying to script a javascript code for testing purpose on LoadRunner. I want to select a particular date on a calendar popup

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a JavaScript code for loadRunner to test an application which contains a  date textbox field.

I wanted to know a JavaScript, where the user can click on a particular date say 25 in the a calendar popup.

By default, the textbox is empty and the user need to click on the textbox/the calendar icon, to show the calendar pop up. In the application, the calendar popup is a `table` with an `id` and each row in the calendar in a `td` tag as per the HTML code. The textbox do not accept any characters, the only option is select from the calendar.

I am able to view the table  with the code

```
var table=document.getElementById("tableid");
```

after this what to write to how to select a particular gridcell.

Answer (score 0):

As for me it is much more convenient to use jQuery for DOM manipulations, but if you insist on pure JS, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('tableid').getElementsByTagName('td')[4].click()
```

`.getElementsByTagName('td')` returns HTML collection (Array) of all tds in your table, so you can access each of them by square bracket notation specifying the index of td in question (4 in my example). Then you simply trigger `click` event on it